# (True or False) for a continuous random variable question

Tags: probability

> Suppose$ X_n$ is a continuous random variable with density $fx_n$(x)= ${(1+ \frac XN)\over(1+ \frac {1} {2n})}$   where $0<x<1$ and is 0 otherwise.  Then {$X_n$} converges in distribution X~ Uniform[0,1]

I did this by integrating f(x) on (0,1) and find out it actually equals to 1, is there any possibly better way to answer this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$ is said to *converge in distribution* to the random variable $X$ if
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n(x)=F(x)
\end{align*}
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ where $F$ is continuous. Here, $F$ and $F_n$ denote the cumulative distribution function of $X$ and $X_n$ ($n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$), respectively.

Now we know that
\begin{align*}
F(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if $x\leq 0$;}\\x&\text{if $x\in(0,1]$;}\\1&\text{if $x>1$,}\end{cases}
\end{align*}
since $X$ is uniform on $[0,1]$. Note that $F$ is continuous everywhere, so that we need to check pointwise converge for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Remember that $F_n(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_n(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$. This integral equals $0$ if $x\leq0$, it equals
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_n(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_{-\infty}^0(0)\mathrm{d}t+\int_0^x\frac{1+t/n}{1+1/(2n)}\,\mathrm{d}t=0+\frac{t+t^2/(2n)}{1+1/(2n)}\Bigg|_0^x=\frac{x+x^2/(2n)}{1+1/(2n)}
\end{align*}
whenever $x\in(0,1]$, and the integral defining $F_n(x)$ is
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^0(0)\mathrm{d}t+\int_0^1\frac{1+t/n}{1+1/(2n)}\,\mathrm{d}t+\int_{1}^{\infty}(0)\mathrm{d}t=0+\frac{t+t^2/(2n)}{1+1/(2n)}\Bigg|_0^1+0=1
\end{align*}
whenever $x>1$.

Comparing the expressions for $F$ and $F_n$, all we left to do is check whether $F_n(x)$ converges to $F(x)$ for $x\in[0,1)$. But whenever $x\in[0,1)$,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} F_n(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x+x^2/(2n)}{1+1/(2n)}=x=F(x),
\end{align*}
and we're done.

Comment: thank you so much! Now i know what to do with this kind of questions

Comment: @RoyWang You're welcome. Good luck with problem solving.